# OfficeJS addHandlerAsync callback does not execute angular component method

Tags: javascript, angular, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an outlook web add-in (in Angular 5) and I am implementing a pinnable task pane and I've been following this documentation from Microsoft : [Implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane).

What I want to do is when the selected mail in Outlook was changed, I need to update the content of my task pane UI.

**On My Component.TS**
I added the following addHandlerSync event listener for change on mail selection:

```
ngOnInit() {
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, this.selectMailChanged);
}
selectMailChanged(){
    this.getPhoneNumbers() //This function gets phone numbers on the email
}
```

The error of the above code is

> `this.getPhoneNumbers is not defined`.

I tried enclosing this *this.getPhoneNumbers* on zone (based on [MS Documentation: Trigger the UI update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2#trigger-the-ui-update)) but it returns zone.run is not defined.

How can I call an angular component method on addHandlerAsync callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good old famous `this` keyword problems.

You're getting that error message because of the context difference. When you're writing the code, the method `selectMailChanged` references the method `getPhoneNumbers` (which I'm hoping you have it implemented) in your component. So coding-wise it looks good.

But when the event kicks in - it doesn't have the context of the component anymore, because it's just calling a callback function - so it doesn't really have all the outside world information except the function that it's calling into. You can read a few good answers about this below:

1. [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
2. https://thenewstack.io/mastering-javascript-callbacks-bind-apply-call/
3. https://technology.amis.nl/2016/08/23/access-the-original-calling-context-in-a-callback-function-in-typescript/

Move the functionality in `getPhoneNumbers` to the callback method and you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful insights! I was able to fix the problem.